# Android: Extending ActionBarActivity crashes the application

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I am using v7-appcompat as library in my app, i am using IntelliJ-IDEA and imported the appcompat library in the project directory. The library has been integrated since i am getting auto-complete suggestions and the project is showing no errors, i am using the theme "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" which is also working properly the problem arises when i run the app on the emulator which crashes when the activity which implements "ActionBarActivity" is triggered rest of the activities which implements "Activity" run fine with the AppCompat theme being implemented.

This Activity runs fine:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;


public class home extends Activity{
private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
Button btnPoetry;
Button btnProse;
Button btnBiography;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);

    btnPoetry = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPoetry);
    btnPoetry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(home.this, poetry.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    btnProse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnProse);
    btnProse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(home.this, prose.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    btnBiography = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBiography);
    btnBiography.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(home.this, biography.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultIntent());
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.settings:
            break;
        case R.id.legend:
            break;
        case R.id.aboutUs:
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private Intent getDefaultIntent(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Extra Text");
    return intent;
}
}
```

Activities like these crash:

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;


public class biography extends ActionBarActivity{
ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
Button btnPictures;
Button btnLW;
Button btnLN;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.biography);

    setUpActionBar();

    btnPictures = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPictures);
    btnPictures.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(biography.this, pictures.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    btnLW = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLW);
    btnLW.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(biography.this, literature.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    btnLN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLN);
    btnLN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(biography.this, lifetimes.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

private void setUpActionBar(){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }else{
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar supportActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        supportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultIntent());
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.settings:
            break;
        case R.id.legend:
            break;
        case R.id.aboutUs:
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private Intent getDefaultIntent(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Extra Text");
    return intent;
}

}
```

Styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="Theme.BaseStyle" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

</style>
<style name="CustomButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerHorizontal">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:capitalize">characters</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1.2</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1.2</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">2</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:color">#669900</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
<style name="CustomTextViewStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">80000</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">3dp</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Logcat:

```
08-05 19:35:11.810    1153-1153/com.faizanbashir.zindarud W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to           resolve static field 1630 (ActionBarWindow) in Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable;
08-05 19:35:11.810    1153-1153/com.faizanbashir.zindarud D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0004
08-05 19:35:11.829    1153-1153/com.faizanbashir.zindarud D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
08-05 19:35:11.829    1153-1153/com.faizanbashir.zindarud W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
08-05 19:35:11.859    1153-1153/com.faizanbashir.zindarud E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
        at  android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:104)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:57)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
        at com.faizanbashir.zindarud.poetry.onCreate(poetry.java:24)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.faizanbashir.zindarud"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
                 android:maxSdkVersion="19" />
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/allama" android:theme="@style/Theme.BaseStyle">
    <activity android:name="main"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".home"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".poetry"
              android:label="@string/Poetry">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".prose"
              android:label="@string/Prose">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".persian"
              android:label="@string/persianPoetry">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".urdu"
              android:label="@string/urduPoetry">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".biography"
              android:label="@string/Biography">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".pictures"
              android:label="@string/Pictures">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".literature"
              android:label="@string/LiteraryWorks">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".lifetimes"
              android:label="@string/LN">
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to do the following ([from Support Library Setup](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html)):

> Right-click the library project folder and select Build Path >
>   Configure Build Path.
>
> In the Order and Export tab, check the .jar files you just added to
>   the build path, so they are available to projects that depend on this
>   library project. For example, the appcompat project requires you to
>   export both the android-support-v4.jar and
>   android-support-v7-appcompat.jar files.
>
> Uncheck Android Dependencies.

Comment: im using IntelliJ but i have already imported the appcompat as a library project.